# MySQL complex query

Tags: mysql

Hello stackoverflow community!

I'm having trouble creating a mysql query.

I have 2 tables:

1) vehicles(engine_id)

2) engines(id, power)

I need to select all the vehicles, whose engine's power is > than some value. 
Could you please help me with that ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT *
      FROM Vehicles
INNER JOIN Engines On Vehicles.engine_id = engines.id
     WHERE Engines.power > yourValues
```

Comment: On MYSQL this will be the fastest.